# "react-native log-android" Error "adb' logcat -c" failed. adb' logcat -c runs fine. [Ubuntu]

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu, adb, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run  react-native log-android to test uploading google photos on my react-native phone app. I get the error

```
warn The following packages use deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release:
  - react-native-fetch-blob: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob#readme
  - react-native-google-signin: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.



info Starting logkitty
/bin/sh: 1: /home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: not found
error Command failed: '/home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' logcat -c
/bin/sh: 1: /home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: not found
. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: '/home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' logcat -c
/bin/sh: 1: /home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: not found





    at spawnLogcatProcess (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/logkitty/build/android/adb.js:36:11)
    at runAndroidLoggingProcess (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/logkitty/build/android/adb.js:21:10)
    at logkitty (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/logkitty/build/api.js:137:85)
    at Object.logAndroid [as func] (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/logAndroid/index.js:37:44)
    at Command.handleAction (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:160:21)
    at Command.listener (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/cliEntry.js:210:24)
```

but when i type adb logcat -c or adb 'logcat -c into the console it works fine.

```
diamonddoesnt@diamonddoesnt-ThinkPad-X260:~/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3$ adb logcat -c
diamonddoesnt@diamonddoesnt-ThinkPad-X260:~/Desktop/prog/it project/react/project/COMP30022-DiamondDoesnt/family3$ adb' logcat -c
```

and i think i have included it into the path, my .bashrc looks like

```
## added
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/lib"
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yTermPlayer"
export PATH="/home/diamonddoesnt/Desktop/prog/it project/flutter/flutter/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb
export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

So im not sure why its giving me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried cd to find /home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb. It didnt work, but when i cd /home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/, it did work. It seems silly but the problem was that in my /Android folder, the sdk folder was named Sdk. So i modified .bashrc  line

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
```

to reflect that and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The script is trying to run `/home/diamonddoesnt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`, fully qualified. Your adb is in your PATH, but it's not there. When you try to run a program with a fully qualified path, it doesn't bother checking your PATH if it doesn't find it there. When you just run it as `adb`, it does check your PATH, explaining the difference. To fix it, do `which adb` to figure out where the binary really is, and reconfigure the script to use that one.

Comment: Sorry for newbie question, but which script do i modify? something in .bashrc or something in my react native project?